# Двойная вероятность случайного числа

Tags: java, случайные-числа, теория-вероятностей

У меня имеются группы фруктов.

Группа 1 - Яблоки 5%, Груши - 5%, апельсины - 10%

Группа 2 - Яблоки 1%, Груши - 80%, апельсины - 19%

Группа 3 - Яблоки 0,01%, Груши - 0,01%, апельсины - 0,01%

Не могу понять, как сделать функцию вероятности вытащить или не вытащить фрукт, и если вытащить, то вероятность "какой фрукт", применимый для каждой группы отдельно.

Метод ниже не решает мою задачу, ибо у меня разные вероятности для каждой группы, и сумма вероятностей всегда разная, + нужно учитывать начальный рандом из 100%, чтоб попасть на пустоту, то есть не вытащить ничего.

```
public int getRandomInt(){
  double x = new Random().nextDouble();
  if(x < 20) return 3;
  else if(x >= 20 && x < 50) return 2;
  else return 1;
}
```

**Дополню**, что кол-во фруктов в группе, может быть разное. Может быть 2 фрукта, а может 50, но все разные, без дубликатов.

Comment: Что значат проценты в группах и почему они не образуют сумму в 100?

Comment: @Kromster как я понял, это он и имел в виду под "пустотой", остальные проценты - шанс вообще не вытащить никакой фрукт, то есть "пустота" :)

Comment: Тогда непонятно, что мешает добавить "пустоту" и дополнить текущий код.

Comment: дополнил вопрос, тем что состав групп может быть разные, и проценты разные. поэтому построить if else заранее не могу.

Answer (score 1):

```
Вероятность вытащить фрукт А =  
Вероятность_работать_с_группой_1*Вероятность_вытащить_фрукт_А_в_группе_1+
+Вероятность_работать_с_группой_2*Вероятность_вытащить_фрукт_А_в группе_2+
+..........+
+Вероятность_работать_с_группой_N*Вероятность_вытащить_фрукт_А_в_группе_N
```

Если все возможные названия фруктов известны - то данные представляются матрицей Nx(M+1), где N-количество групп, M-количество видов фруктов (+1 для вероятности "ничего не вытащить" и не возиться с 1-сумма остальных вероятностей по строке).

Если все возможные названия фруктов неизвестны, то  -  например -  данные организуются в в  группе в виде списка, и надо проверять, имеется-ли данный фрукт в данной группе.